# Nuxt3 + Tailwind Css => postcss@8 is not compatible with current version of nuxt (0.0.0). Expected: >=2.15.3

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, postcss, nuxtjs3

Cannot figure out this error...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, as Nuxt 3 requires a different way to integrate Tailwind. The following is to install Tailwind as a Nuxt module, rather than independently. This is easier, as it requires a lot less configuration (no need to edit *postcss.config.js*, a bit less config required for *nuxt.config.js*).

[Version 5.0 of the Nuxt Tailwind module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module/releases/tag/v5.0.0-0) brings in support for Nuxt 3. Full default installation is as follows:

### Step 1

To install, we can dev install this (yarn add or npm install) with *@nuxtjs/tailwindcss@latest* or whichever version (after 5.1) you need.

```
 yarn add -D @nuxtjs/tailwindcss@latest
```

### Step 2

Then in **nuxt.config.js**, add the module to the modules array:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt"

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
    ]
})
```

### Step 3

Create a tailwind.config.js file either manually or by using the terminal command:

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

### Step 4

Add the Tailwind directives to your main CSS file (./assets/css/tailwind.css by default, or [configurable in your nuxt.config.js file](https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/options)).

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

### Step 5

After this, try running your dev or build commands, and it should be working correctly.